# select the second line to last line of a file

Tags: linux, unix, tail, unix-head

How can I select the lines from the second line to the line before the last line of a file by using `head` and `tail` in unix?

For example if my file has 15 lines I want to select lines from 2 to 14.

Comment: See #49 http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-two/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
tail -n +2 /path/to/file | head -n -1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ne 'print if($.!=1 and !(eof))' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
> perl -ne 'print if($.!=1 and !(eof))' temp
2
3
4
5
6
>
```

alternatively in awk you can use below:

```
awk '{a[count++]=$0}END{for(i=1;i<count-1;i++) print a[i]}' your_file
```

Answer (score 1):

To print all lines but first and last ones you can use this `awk` as well:

```
awk 'NR==1 {next} {if (f) print f; f=$0}'
```

This always prints the previous line. To prevent the first one from being printed, we skip the line when `NR` is 1. Then, the last one won't be printed because when reading it we are printing the penultimate!

#### Test

```
$ seq 10 | awk 'NR==1 {next} {if (f) print f; f=$0}'
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```